# rowkey attribute in primefaces is not rendered, without selection or selectionMode attribute

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, selection

I want use the `rowkey` attribute within a `datatable` primefaces (for use it in javascript script),
but I've noticed that is necessary set at least the `selectionMode` or `selection` attribute,
otherwise the `rowkey`attribute (`data-rk`) is not rendered.
It 's true, or am I wrong?
I did some tests and it seems to be so.

Below an example from the showcase:
(`rowkey` attribute seems to be always used in combination with the `selectionMode` or `selection` attribute)

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml

I would need to take advantage of the `rowkey` attribute without using `selectionMode` or `selection` attribute;
you would know how to do?

Or, you know how to set a custom attribute for each row of datatable without using the component `p:row`;
The only thing that comes to mind is use the `rowClass` attribute to insert in, the value of a bean property,

as is the case here

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/rowColor.xhtml

But I wanted to associate the property of the bean to a specific attribute of row without creating a fake class CSS.

thanks in advance

Comment: which version of primefaces and jsf?

Comment: primefaces-4.0 and jsf_1.0.0.0_2-0

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to achieve the presence of 'data-rk' attribute on a `<tr>` without the rendering of the selection column.

I did some tests and if you put this styling on the  then you will not have the selection column but still the 'data-k' attribute:

```
<p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="display: none;" />
```

You have to put this tag, but **you do not need** to place the selection attribute on the `<p:dataTable>`.

If this is what you are looking for, then this worked for me on Primefaces 6.0 and JSF 2.2

Comment: Hi Maciej, thanks for the answer; actually I cannot insert a new column on the datatable. Have you other ideas?

Comment: Is it due to the versions? Otherwise i dont see the reason why not to.. its not rendered anywya

Comment: I'm sorry I have not explained it well: I can not add the column due to functional specifications, not because I can not programmatically.

Comment: I see. I will try more things later on

Comment: Can you bind the table to a property in a bean?

Comment: I cannot see any problem with bind...what is your idea?